# Is it possible for my prometheus container to pull metrics from Azure Monitor?

Tags: azure, docker, prometheus, monitoring, azure-monitoring

I'm setting up a Prometheus instance (running in a Docker container) to monitor Azure services. I've read about using the Azure Monitor Exporter for this purpose, but I'm unsure how to correctly integrate it with my Prometheus setup.

How can I setup the Prometheus-container to pull metrics from Azure services like PostgreSQL and Blob Storage?

Any advice, resources, or examples of how this can be accomplished would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the `Installation and Configuration of Azure Metrics Exporter` section of https://logz.io/learn/guide-to-azure-monitoring-with-prometheus/